# PHP: ASCII and UTF-8 strings comparison

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii

I have following test.php script:

```
$AES_IV = "4epZqMl8BQukhip6WQjQHg==";
$AES_KEY = "zvKmer0cPiJdQQ1RPjQOCF/wURt+31UdingRoPj4+Yc=";

$guid = $_GET["guid"];
$encryptedGuid = urldecode($_GET["encryptedGuid"]);

$decryptedGuid = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, base64_decode($AES_KEY), base64_decode($encryptedGuid), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, base64_decode($AES_IV));

echo "Guid is: ".$guid."</br>";
echo "Decrypted GUID is: ".$decryptedGuid."</br>";

if ($decryptedGuid === $guid)
{
    echo "Guid and decrypted Guid are equals.";
}
else 
{
    echo "Guid and decrypted Guid are not equals.";
}
```

I call this script as follows:

```
http://localhost:8087/test/test.php?guid=08201E62-DFA5-8A50-ACFC-A811871804CD&encryptedGuid=ED40y72BJvzXmN0Aj9eb85VdIJKu6LUYQuYSWMPOhIQcm5SIquZAhRMmhsC7ax2e
```

Test.php script should display "Guid and decrypted Guid are equals." but it never occurs. I tried to check encoding of strings and $guid is ASCII and $encryptedGuid is UTF-8. Can you please help me how to solve this problem? I tried to convert ASCII to UTF-8 but I wasn't successful because result of e.g. iconv function was again ASCII. I think convert ASCII to UTF-8 can be solution but I am not sure if it is always true that $_GET returns ASCII.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: UTF-8 is 100% ASCII compatible, so this can't be the problem.

Comment: What does your script say about the values of `$guid` and `$decryptedGuid`? Also, you're not suppose to `urldecode` the values in `$_GET`.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder, if mcrypt inserts a byte order mark, it certainly can. Try doing the comparison character by character and/or check the length of the string, verifying that there are no invisible characters, like the BOM (Unicode U+FEFF) or other funny stuff.

Comment: @DennisKrøger `mcrypt_decrypt` works with arbitrary binary data. It doesn't care about text, encodings or BOM's...

Comment: @Vatev: Nope, but it apparently pads (or at least something does). Just tested with bin2hex, the decrypted string has "0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c" added.

Comment: Hmmm... It seems like the padding is from the encryption, but it is something you seem to have chosen yourself, the default is 0 padding? (presuming it was also encrypted using mcrypt). Anyway, you should be able to remove it using rtrim($decryptedString).

Comment: Sorry, I thought it is not important but I use RijndaelManaged classs (.NET, C#) to encrypt GUID. Default padding is PKCS7. On http://de2.php.net/function.mcrypt-decrypt page it is possible to find how to remove PKCS7 padding. Thank you so much for idea with padding. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I was able to work it out thanks to Dennis' comment about **padding**.

After I decrypted my AES string and I noticed that one particular param in the URL wasn't quite right...

```
E.g. test=1&foo=bar
```

It looked fine. However, when I was trying to do a string comparison with the final value in the URL (bar) it would never be true.

```
if ($foo == 'bar')
```

So, I compared the strings using `bin2hex` there was some sort of repeated string added to the end of the param value (0505050505). What I didn't realise was that this was padding added to the string by the encryption.

For some reason rtrim didn't help me so what I did was added a useless param to the end of my URL before encryption (e.g. padding=1). This made sure that the last of my "important" params didn't have the padding added to the string.